# Is there some 3D printing process that puts enamel layers on the 3D printed metal?

Tags: color

I would like to custom design and print a medal (sign of chivalry order). I know that I can make 3D design and 3D print it in metal, but are there 3D printing processes that put some layers of enamel in different colors? Possibly with gradual moves among the colors, something like roses in the Brazil Imperial Order of Roses https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_the_Rose#/media/File:Order_of_the_Rose.jpg ? Is it possible to 3D print structure like that?

As I am googling for such process, I have found that there is 3D ceramic printing process and that is very close to the enamel. There is also transparent color 3D printing attempts, so - feel that this may be possible. But I am new to this field and I would like to get some prima facie estimation of the possibility to print such order-like structure in (any) metal plus enamel/ceramic material.

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to be a "shopping" question.

Comment: I updated my question - I found and put a bit worse picture of the sample order but it is from the wikipedia and not from the open sale offer. Hope, that now the close vote can be removed.